# Customer sign in not working

Tags: magento2, customer-registration

I'm using Magento 2.3.5 and I am not able to create a new customer account on the frontend. I've been stuck on this issue for days and I'm not sure what is causing this. I'm not receiving any errors.

The `customer/account/create` page I use has forms from two different `register.phtml`.

One is located here `vendor/clarion/customer-attribute/view/frontend/templates/account/register.phtml` (which consists of customer attributes created on the admin) and

the other one is `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml`.

I have tried to disable the `Clarion_CusterAttribute` module but it doesn't help.

My cookie configuration is as follows. I'm not sure what is wrong. I also have to restart php.fpm every time I make changes to any phtml files but this is probably a separate issue.
[image]

Not sure if this is relevant but when I click the `create the account` button, it calls a cms registration page to basically send out a confirmation message that your account has been made and then refreshes to your account page.

But no new customer data is being added to the admin page.
Here is the registration page
[image]

I am, however, able to edit and update account information once logged (made thru the admin). These changes do get reflected on the admin page.

Comment: Have you checked the page: https://www.yourwebsite.com/customer/account/login/, since that's the Magento legit registration page

Comment: Logging in works fine.